# Postgresql crosstab from three tables

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I have three tables in my database that I want to merge them and display them using `crosstab` function, please check this picture :
[image]

So what I'vre tried to do, [by following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905), is to join these three tables in one view and then use `crosstab` on it like this:

```
create or replace view t as
SELECT a.code as code_an, n.code as code_n, montant
FROM analytic a JOIN analytic_has_nature ON (a.id = id_analytic)
JOIN nature n ON (n.id = id_nature);
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
      'SELECT code_an, code_n, montant
       FROM   t
       ORDER  BY 1,2')
AS t2 (code_an character varying(50), code_n character varying(50), montant double precision);
```

unfortunately, Postgresql shows me this error:

```
ERREUR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the return tuple you have one column with `code_n` and three columns of type `double precision`.
In your example `code_n` is a row identifier and `code_an` is a category, so replace them in the first query.
Also, add the second query to define categories (it ensures the correct distribution of incomplete data):

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
      'SELECT code_n, code_an, montant
       FROM   t
       ORDER  BY 1,2',
      'VALUES (''PDR''), (''EQ''), (''DIV'')')
AS t2 ( code_n character varying(50), 
        "PDR" double precision,
        "EQ" double precision, 
        "DIV" double precision);
```

Comment: ah thnx it works :), but is it possible to get those columns dynamicly ?I mean it can be more than 3 columns ex: PDR, EQ, DIV, SOP, ...

Comment: Of course, you can `SELECT DISTINCT code_an FROM t ORDER BY 1` (or without order).

Comment: You can use this `SELECT`as the second query but you have to explicitly write down column names and types in the return tuple type declaration, and ensure the order is the same.